# Two finger moving smooth and kinetic scrolling with trackpad or touchpad?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I am working on a Qt application which resembles **hex editor** for Mac. 
(picture from Google)
[image]

It has a very large portion of data to scroll vertically(upward and downward) because it shows all large files data in hex format.

In my application, I'd like to add two finger smooth scrolling in both direction: up and down like that in Macbook Air two finger scrolling.
It work properly with mouse wheel but not with trackpad two finger move scrolling.

If someone has a solution, please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your post to have acceptable English, and tell us what you've already tried.

Answer (score 1):

The scroller allows for gestures like click and drag to do kinetic scrolling.

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qscroller.html#details

Note on this page:

```
QScroller::TouchGesture 0 
The gesture recognizer will only trigger on touch events. Specifically it will react on single touch points when using a touch screen and dual touch points when using a touchpad.
```

So then the example they give would turn into this for you:

```
QWidget *w = ...;
QScroller::grabGesture(w, QScroller::TouchGesture);
```

There is more on doing new things with touch screens and touch pads by handling the QTouchEvent:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtouchevent.html#details

Hope that helps.

Comment: Actualy i am working on Qt 4.6 and there is no Class named QScroller. Please suggest me alternate solution.

Comment: Qt 5.x isn't an option?  I don't think touch has been supported well previously.  You can also try to implement your own kinetic scrolling and make it so that the QScrollArea that you have it in has a strong focus.  Then handle the mouseScrollEvents to do kinetic scrolling.

Comment: Some other ways to get it to happen on Qt 4.x: https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2009/07/19/kinetic-scrolling-on-any-widgets/
http://developer.nokia.com/community/discussion/showthread.php/214378-QScrollArea-and-finger-scroll

Comment: Its working perfectly with mouse wheel , but with trackpad or touchpad moving two fingers verticaly(upward and downward) it reads only as one scroll(as we move mouse wheel only one time).

Comment: How to get mouseWheel.delta() with trackpad, moving two finger.

Comment: I haven't checked how it is sent over when performed on a mac or on a PC with two finger scrolling support.  I believe it arrives the same way that a standard scroll arrives.  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwheelevent.html  http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#wheelEvent